# Encajar imagen en contenedor

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Alguien podría ayudarme a hacer que las imágenes ocupen toda la altura de su respectiva box? Como podrán observar, abajo se queda un pequeño espacio con el color del background, que me gustaría que se ocupara con la imagen.

```css
.projects-box {
  background: RoyalBlue;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 4% auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.individual-box {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.individual-box img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-box">
        <div class="individual-box">
            <img src="img/img.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <p>Proyecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <img src="img/img.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <p>Proyecto</p>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con añadir la propiedad `display: flex` a `.individual-box` lo  conseguirías. Pero esto ocasionaría que el texto dejase de estar alineado en el centro.

Para que siga con esa alineación te bastaría añadirle también `justify-content: center`.

```css
.projects-box {
  background: RoyalBlue;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 4% auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.individual-box {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.individual-box img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-box">
        <div class="individual-box">
            <img src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/534533867.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <p>Proyecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <img src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/534533867.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="individual-box">
            <p>Proyecto</p>
        </div>      
    </div>
```